# Reset print drivers through GPO

Tags: printing, driver, policy

I am pushing print drivers to users from SCCM with no issue. The drivers are set to black and white default. What happens is that when a user prints, they may change the settings to colour, but they then stay as colour until manually changed back. I need the driver to reset to default. Maybe not after each job but definitely at restart / logon? Cannot find anything to acheive this, but I know that it was done in the past.